# Shell scripts doesn't pass arguments to application

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have this 1 line shell script:

```
"/Applications/TexturePacker.app/Contents/MacOS/TexturePacker" "PSD_files/default_atlas/" --sheet "default_atlas.png" --format xml --data "default_atlas.xml" --premultiply-alpha
```

When I run the command directly, it works as expected - `TexturePacker` application is started using the specified parameters, but when I put exactly the same line inside a .sh file and execute it, `TexturePacker` doesn't receive the parameters (help message appears as if the application was started without parameters).

How may I run the same command from a .sh file?

PS: I tried to add `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` before the line with the same results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: as you mentioned in your reply, there was a problem with your line endings in the script file. 
When you run it via bash -x it will run in debug mode, giving you the option to see everything the shell script is doing. 
So, try this and copy paste its output if you still have trouble.

```
#!/bin/bash -x 
/Applications/TexturePacker.app/Contents/MacOS/TexturePacker PSD_files/default_atlas/ --sheet "default_atlas.png" --format xml --data "default_atlas.xml" --premultiply-alpha
```

In other words, there was nothing wrong with your code, only your file format.

Comment: If I add #!/bin/bash -x the output is missing completely (even for the simple echo "a")

Comment: That means you have a more serious problem. 
What happens if you execute your test script interactively:

    bash -x testscript.sh

?  (you are using /bin/bash right? not /bin/sh ? )

Comment: I think I found the problem, I'm using jsx from Adobe to write the files and it seems it converting line endings to Windows style which confuses bash...

Comment: This is a request for clarification, not an answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks, Didn't know that, but seeing how it wasn't a problem with the code, I've modified my response. Fixed :p

Answer (score 1):

The script file was created using Adobe JSX File class which inserted Windows style line endings, even though the `lineFeed` property was set to "Macintosh". This thing confused shell and the output was completely missing (even in debug mode)